# About HtML5 Footer tag

Tags: html

I want to add three things in the following footer section. In which tags these should be placed?

1. Navigation menu.
2. Email.
3. Copyright (Just a small line "Copyright © 2011 All Rights")

> ```
> <footer>
>       <address>
>       Website:<br />
>       <a href="www.example.com">Website
>       </address>
>     </footer>
> ```

PS. I am asking as I don't know if these things should be inside the `<address>` tag, or `<p>` tag or something else.

Answer (score 8):

> 1 . Navigation menu.

You should create `nav` tag for this. You can view an example [here](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/).

> 2 . Email.

For the email you should place within the address tag. You can view the details [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/).

> 3 . Copyright (Just a small line "Copyright © 2011 All Rights")

The copyright may be surrounded by the paragraph tag (`<p></p>`). You can view some examples of its usage on the W3C HTML5 site: [4.4.9 The footer element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-footer-element). You could surround it by the `small` tag before surrounding it by the `p` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The copyright should be enclosed in a `small` element as mentioned, although I don't think that you need a `p`, but that's just personal preference.

**editing based on being correctly corrected below, ignore what's in the square brackets below**

[The `address` element should not be used for the email address! Even the link that Alerty provides above says this! I would simply keep it within an `a` element within a `span` or `div`.]

Comment: A quote of the W3C within the link I provided for the address tag says this: "The address element provides contact information for a document or part of a document. Information provided by address may include the names of the document’s maintainers, links to the maintainers’ Web pages, e-mail addresses for feedback, postal addresses, phone numbers, and so on. The address element is not appropriate for all postal and e-mail addresses; it should be reserved for providing such information about the contact people for the document."

Comment: Also, have a look at the HTML5 spec about the address tag here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-address-element.

Comment: Notice the example that is given by the W3C in the HTML5 spec. Within the address tag there is an email address surrounded be an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate to put the email address in the address element if (and only if) the email address provides contact info for the page as a whole.

The current version of the HTML5 spec says, "The address element represents the contact information for its nearest article or body element ancestor."

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#the-address-element